# How to add numbers to new lines in textfield?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `textfield` that the user can enter multiple lines of text into. I would like the `textfield` to number the text every time the user presses `enter` to go to a new line, like below:

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vulputate.
2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur malesuada est in turpis ultricies, vel auctor mauris scelerisque. Morbi vitae
4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque scelerisque ante eu elit euismod, eget.
5. Lorem ipsum dolor

My code for the `textfield` with a numbered hint text:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
        children: [
                      const Text(
                        'Instructions:',
                        style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(14),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: mobileSearchColor),
                        child: TextField(
                          style: TextStyle(height: 2),
                          controller: _textAreaController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          maxLines: 10,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                            hintText: '1.\n2.\n3.\n4.\n5.\n',
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(width: 1, color: primaryColor),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

I've looked at [bulleted_list](https://pub.dev/packages/bulleted_list) but it seems to only display bulleted lists, which I'll be using later to display the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put any value inside textfield using TextFieldController and put any value using controller.text = value;
In textfield onChange apply these condition.

(1) check that value is end with \n then add number you can check like this:

```
onChange: (value) {
    if (value.endWith('\n')) {
        controller.text = value + yourValue;
    }
}
```

(2) After adding you have to set the cursor at end of textfield so implement that if you can't set cursor position you will find the implementation here.

(3) And also when you will erase the value into textfield then yourValue will be entered to fix it check that textfield value length is increasing or decreasing to that you can store previous value in any variable and then check it with current onChange value if  previous value length is less than current value then add or put your number or youValue inside textfilled otherwise do nothing and don't forget to update the previous value in last.